# Validation: Bad value first for attribute rel on element link

Tags: html, validation, rel

I'm using Piwigo photo gallery software and it dynamically generates some code in the head of the page, which displays like this:

```
<link rel="first" title="First" href="picture.php?/2601/category/37">
<link rel="prev" title="Previous" href="picture.php?/2619/category/37">
<link rel="next" title="Next" href="picture.php?/2621/category/37">
<link rel="last" title="Last" href="picture.php?/2760/category/37">
<link rel="up" title="Thumbnails" href="index.php?/category/37">
```

When I run it through the validator, I get errors as follows:

```
Line 21, Column 71: Bad value first for attribute rel on element link: The string first is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.
…" href="picture.php?/2601/category/37">  <link rel="prev" title="Previous" hre…

Line 21, Column 282: Bad value last for attribute rel on element link: The string last is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.
…" href="picture.php?/2760/category/37">  <link rel="up" title="Thumbnails" hre…

 Line 21, Column 348: Bad value up for attribute rel on element link: The string up is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.
…category/37">  <link rel="up" title="Thumbnails" href="index.php?/category/37">
```

After some reading, I have come to understand that HTML5 has removed rel up, first and last, though it has kept prev and next. What I don't understand though is what to replace up, first and next with? If I remove them completely, the validator isn't happy with that either.

Does anyone know? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5 you are only allowed to use the following values for the `rel` attribute:

- [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes)
- [registered in the Microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions)

If you need another link type, you would have to [register it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types).

---

About the removal of `first`/`index`: [Semantics of rel=first and rel=index breaks specs and implementations](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=7475).

Answer (score 1):

Using a temp plate w3c and on the gallery page found  rel="title" Which caused val failure  Taken it out of script But I have no idea what it did what Attribute Values after testing website on all platforms still have no idea what it was doing 
rel="title"

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem with validator (when used fancybox plugin).
You can replace `rel` to something like `data-rel` and make appropriate changes in your scripts (i.e. for fancybox we need to replace all `attr('rel')` with `attr('data-rel')`